# Nested query not fetching data correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Problem**

I have two different tables, table names are **team_request** and **teams**. **[team_request]** have unique records of each team submitted and **[teams]** saves duplicate records with unique username's but same team data as in **[team_request]** for the user who accepted to be part of that team.

*Expected result from below query:*

I am running the below query to fetch the pending challenges or team request, which have a basic logic of fetch all the teams from **[team_request]** where that team doesn't exists in **[teams]** table or hasn't been ignored by that user.

*Actually what query is doing:*

It's fetching all the rows (teams) from table **[team_request]** which belongs to that user, no matter whether a user has excepted or ignored.

Also forgot to mention above **fbC_status** is a field in **[team_request]** which saves user's email address if that user has ignored to be part of the team.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated I just got stuck with it.

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM team_request
WHERE (c_emails LIKE '%joe@example.com%')
  OR (c_emails LIKE '%9876543210%')
  AND fbC_status NOT LIKE '%joe@example.com%'
  AND fbC_status NOT LIKE '%9876543210%'
  AND '%joe@example.com%' NOT IN
    (SELECT username
     FROM teams)
  AND t_name NOT IN
    (SELECT T.t_name
     FROM team_request TR,
          teams T
     WHERE TR.t_name = T.t_name
       AND T.username = '%joe@example.com%'
       AND (TR.fbC_status NOT LIKE '%joe@example.com%'
            AND TR.fbC_status NOT LIKE '%9876543210%')) 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: Whats the deal with `'%9876543210%'`? Am I right in thinking you what you are trying to do is: Get records that are in `team_request` but not `teams` table and where `fbC_Status` does not contain an email address?

Comment: yes but also that number, that number is a phone number of a person as am using this query in AJAX while building an phonegap app. So yes you are correct but also it is **Get records that are in team_request but not teams table and where fbC_Status does not contain an email address or phone number** Sorry I missed that in the question

Comment: I don't want to sift through that. Post up some proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Note also that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you rethink how your database is structured, your `teams` table appears to be pretty much a duplicate of `team_requests` but given the current structure try something like:

```
@phone would be your '9876543210'
@username would be your 'joe@example.com'

SELECT r.*
FROM team_request r
WHERE (r.c_emails = @username OR r.c_emails = @phone)
  AND r.fbC_status <> r.c_emails
  AND r.t_name NOT IN ( SELECT t.name 
                        FROM teams t
                        WHERE /* t.username = r.c_emails otherwise: */
                              t.username = @username /* OR t.phone = @phone*/

                      )
```

Its fairly unclear what all your fields are used for so this is unlikely to work without changes. The commented out parts are what I suspect you should use, but I have no means of knowing whether or not they would work with your tables.

You can feel free to use your `LIKE '%...%'` however remember that if a user has the email `at@email.com`, when a user with the email `acrobat@email.com` also exists `LIKE '%at@email.com%`' is going to match them both.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try it now! Basically c_emails field saves string of challenged emails or phone numbers sperated by "|", an example "joe@example.com|328913|32930123|mark@example.com". This is the reason why am using **like** and username saves the email address of the user which exists in teams table.

Comment: Ah perfect, easier than expected ;) For the c_emails, I'd recommend storing them as `"|aaa|bbbb|"` (with a `|` before the first and after the last) so you can do LIKE `'%|email|%'` (`|` might be a special character in which case you'd need `'%\|email\|%'`)

Comment: hey nice idea ;) coz that will then not duplicate the usernames while selecting!